Trajectories and Changing Limits of Integration
Although I came across this issue doing physics, the underlying nature of the problem is purely mathematical.
So, Work is defined as $W_p=\int_{\gamma_{p}}\vec F_p\cdot d\vec r_{pa}$ where $\vec F_p$ is the force on particle $p$, $\vec r_{pa}$ is the vector between point $p$ and an inertially fixed point $a$, and $\gamma_{p}$ is the 'trajectory' of $p$. And of course, the standard way to deal with this is to find $\vec v_{pa} = \frac{d}{dt}\vec r_{pa}$ and evaluate the integral $\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\vec F_p\cdot \vec v_{pa}dt$. This makes plenty of intuitive sense. However, I do find myself mildly perturbed by the fact that an integral over position seamlessly transitioned to an integral over time without it really seeming like anything changed, but more on that later. Also, my textbook doesn't really give the trajectory a firm mathematical definition, though I assume it's something like $\{\vec r_{pa}(t): t\in[t_0,t_1]\}$ which would make it dependent both on the point $p$ and on the reference $a$.
Where this starts getting really weird for me is the question of if I know the trajectory of a point with respect to a non-inertial reference point $b$. For example, let's say I throw a ball in an elevator that is accelerating upwards at a constant rate: it should still be a parabola, so it wouldn't be that hard to deduce the full trajectory from a couple measurements. My question is whether the work done by gravity is fundamentally different when calculated with respect to a point $b$ somewhere on the elevator versus the point $a$ on the ground (assuming of course a constant gravitational field).
So to start to figure this out, we'll define $\gamma_{pb}=\{\vec r_{pb}(t):t\in[t_0,t_1]\}$ and attempt to evaluate $\int_{\gamma_{pb}}\vec F_p\cdot d\vec r_{pb}$ in terms of the inertial Work equation and see what else shows up. Of course, $d\vec r_{pb}=(\vec v_{pa}-\vec v_{ba})dt$, so presumably this new integral will evaluate to $W_p - \int_{t_0}^{t_1}\vec F_p \cdot\vec v_{ba}dt$, which would imply that (if the elevator is moving up) then gravity does do extra work on the ball, which would make sense. But hang on, if I go back a step to $\int_{\gamma_{pb}}\vec F_p\cdot d\vec r_{pb}=\int_{\gamma_{pb}}\vec F_p\cdot d\vec r_{pa}-\int_{\gamma_{pb}}\vec F_p\cdot d\vec r_{ba}$, that first term doesn't equal $W_p$ as defined because the trajectories are different. So this goes back to the issue I mentioned earlier: how exactly is the transition from $d\vec r$ to $dt$ handled mathematically, under the hood? Because if I follow the intuitive route and just swap the limits of integration, it seems like there's a subtlety I'm just throwing away.
Many thanks in advance!

I've edited this post because in initially my example stated that the elevator moved at constant velocity, and it was kindly pointed out by David K. that frames that translate constant velocity are also functionally inertial.

By the very definition, the line integral of a vector field is $\int_\gamma F\cdot dr=\int_a^bF(r(t))\cdot r'(t),dt,.$ This definition is designed such that it is independent of the parametrization of the curve $\gamma,.$ That is: the function $t\mapsto r(t)$ only has to have the correct curve's start and end point. We do not have to interpret $t$ as time as long as this requirement is satisfied. You can also arrive at that definition naturally by discretizing the parameter interval and using Riemann sums.

To be precise: Riemann-Stieltjes sums.
